# Import Error on installed package (wikitools)

Tags: python

I have installed `wikitools` using `pip`, but when I write:

```
from wikitools import wiki, api
```

in Python I get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    from wikitools import wiki, api
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\wikitools\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from wiki import *
ImportError: No module named 'wiki'
```

What's the problem here? I'm using Python 3.5.

Answer (score 7):

According to this [page](https://github.com/alexz-enwp/wikitools), `wikitools` is not compatible with Python 3:

> Requirements
>
> 1. Python 2.5+. Not compatible with Python 3; not tested on older versions
> 2. Bob Ippolito's simplejson module, if using Python < 2.6 http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson
> 3. To upload files or import XML, you need Chris AtLee's poster package http://pypi.python.org/pypi/poster
> 4. The wiki this is used for should be running at least MediaWiki version 1.13 and have the API enabled.